# Add classes to list dynamically with enum values

Tags: c#, oop

I'm trying to make a method that creates a list of objects.
The objects are added with enumerator values.

I currently have 2 enumerators: CardType, CardColor.
Assigning the CardType value works as intented but when I use the exact same code to asign the CardColor it always returns the same value(Red).

I've included the switch statement I have already tried in comment form.

Class with main method:

```
 public class CardStack
        {
            Card CardObject;
            List<Card> cardList;
            public CardStack()
            {
                cardList = new List<Card>();
                CardObject = new Card();
            }
            public List<Card> getCardList()
            {     
                for(int i = 1; i <= Enum.GetNames(typeof(CardType)).Length; i++)
                {
                    CardObject.Type = addCardType(i);
                    for(int n =0; n <= 3; n++)
                    {

                        CardObject.Color = addCardColor(n);
                        cardList.Add(CardObject);
                    }

                    CardObject = new Card();
                }
                return cardList;
            }

            public CardColor addCardColor(int colorNumber)
            {
                //Debug.WriteLine(colorNumber.ToString());
                //switch (colorNumber)
                //{

                //    case 0: return CardColor.Green;
                //    case 1: return CardColor.Blue;
                //    case 2: return CardColor.Yellow;
                //    case 3: return CardColor.Red;                
                //    default:
                //        return CardColor.Yellow;
                //}
                return (CardColor)colorNumber;
            }
            public CardType addCardType(int typeNumber)
            {
                return (CardType)typeNumber;
            }

        }
```

Enum CardColor:

```
public enum CardColor
{
    Green,
    Blue,
    Yellow,
    Red
}
```

Enum CardType:

```
public enum CardType
{
   One = 1,
   Two = 2,
   Three = 3,
   Four = 4,
   Five = 5,
   Six = 6,
   Give_2,
   Take_1,
   Which
}
```

My debug output(shortened):

```
 Type: One; Color: Red;
[0:] Type: One; Color: Red;
[0:] Type: One; Color: Red;
[0:] Type: One; Color: Red;
[0:] Type: Two; Color: Red;
[0:] Type: Two; Color: Red;
[0:] Type: Two; Color: Red;
[0:] Type: Two; Color: Red;
[0:] Type: Three; Color: Red;
[0:] Type: Three; Color: Red;
[0:] Type: Three; Color: Red;
[0:] Type: Three; Color: Red;
```

Comment: Move `CardObject = new Card();` to the innermost loop

Comment: What is the usage of `CardObject` as member property? You can make as local variable in the method while adding in `cardList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i = 1; i <= Enum.GetNames(typeof(CardType)).Length; i++)
{
    CardObject.Type = addCardType(i);         // Sets Card Type
    for(int n =0; n <= 3; n++)
    {
        CardObject.Color = addCardColor(n);   //1. Sets Color on THE SAME CardObject
        cardList.Add(CardObject);             //2. Adds THE SAME CardObject 4 times
    }
    CardObject = new Card();                  //3. create new Object => all of the 
                                              // above added references point to
                                              // the same CardObject, which has 
                                              // been set to "Red".
}
```

Solution: Move Line marked with //3. inside the inner for loop, right after //2.

Unrelated:

- I'd recommend to create a parameterized Constructor, so you can simply do `cardList.Add(new Card(type, color))`.
- Since Type and Color of a Card won't change, they should be read-only. In fact `Card` should be [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#C#).
- Just use `foreach` to iterate the [enum values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=netframework-4.8).

---

Improved version:

```
public IEnumerable<Card> GetCardList()
{
    foreach (CardType type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardType)))
    {
        foreach (CardColor color in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardColor)))
        {
            yield return new Card(type,color);
        }
    }
}
```

(see [yield](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) contextual keyword)

Where `Card`:

```
public class Card
{
    public readonly CardType Type;
    public readonly CardColor Color;

    public Card( CardType type, CardColor color )
    {
        this.Type = type;
        this.Color = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: With some slight alerations to your given solution I got it to work. My desired list had 4 objects per type each with a different colour. Hence the //3 outside of the innermost loop but have now declared the type once in the outer loop which I use in the innerloop.

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, in the inner loop, you are modifying the properties of the same instance of Card (CardObject) while adding it to cardList. This would mean, all the reference to have the same value as the Color in the last loop, which in your case would be Red.

What you need to do is to reinitialize the CardObject within the Inner loop. For example,

```
for(int i = 1; i <= Enum.GetNames(typeof(CardType)).Length; i++)
{
    CardObject.Type = addCardType(i);
    for(int n =0; n <= 3; n++)
    {
         CardObject = new Card();   // Change here
         CardObject.Color = addCardColor(n);
         cardList.Add(CardObject);
    }
}
```

This would ensure you are dealing with a new instance of Card every time in the inner loop.

Meanwhile, another approach to accomplish the same using Linq would be

```
var list = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardType))
               .Cast<CardType>()
               .SelectMany(type => Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardColor))
                                       .Cast<CardColor>()
                                       .Select(color => 
                                        new Card {Type = type, Color = color}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach to iterate over the enum-values. Make a new CardObject in each interation (inner loop!) and add them to the list.

```
public class CardStack
{
    private readonly List<Card> _cardList;
    public CardStack()
    {
        _cardList = getCardList();

    }
    private static List<Card> getCardList()
    {
        var localList = new List<Card>();
        foreach (CardType type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardType)))
        {
            foreach (CardColor color in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardColor)))
            {
                var cardObject = new Card(){Type = type, Color = color};
                localList.Add(cardObject);
            }
        }

        return localList;
    }
}
}
```